# Google Apps script, Invalid argument: Name

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sites

I have a google site with some scripts running on time triggers.

I have multiple list pages for different users. 
The script I am using is taking the values from the google sites list page and putting those values in a google sheet.

I am adding a new user and I've copied the code that works for all the previous users and pasted the code for the new user giving it a function name of *UsernameList().

This same code is working for other users but is throwing an error for this one.

Here is the code.

```
      function nicholsonList() {
var site = SitesApp.getSiteByUrl('https://sites.google.com/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');
var page = SitesApp.getPageByUrl("https://sites.google.com/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");

// setting the google spreadsheet
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Nicholson");

// setting loggers to confirm information
Logger.log(site);
Logger.log(page);
Logger.log(ss);
Logger.log(sheet);


sheet.getRange('B2:H22').clearContent();
var items = page.getListItems({ start:0, max: 50 });
var itemslength = items.length;
Logger.log(itemslength);


var item, attrib = 0;
var row = 2;
var attribs = ["", "", "Project", "Description", "Assigned By", "Status", "Start Date", "Due Date", "% Complete", "Job Number", "Comments"];

for (var i in items) { if (items.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
    item = items[i];
    for (var j = 2; j < attribs.length; j++) {
        attrib = item.getValueByName(attribs[j]);
        Logger.log(attrib);
        range = sheet.getRange(row,j)
        var sheetwrite = sheet.setActiveRange(range)
        sheetwrite.setValue(attrib); 
    }

  Logger.log(row);
  Logger.log(j);
  row++;
```

There is some code preceding that points to the correct site address and google sheet and tab name.

I am getting an error on the following line.

```
attrib = item.getValueByName(attribs[j]);
```

The error I am getting is

> Invalid argument: name (line 286, file "Code")

I'm stumped.

I would appreciate any direction you can provide.

**EDIT**

I found the issue some time ago but wanted to update this.

A user had deleted some of the columns in the list page so the script was looking for more items than were present.

Comment: I'd add a `Logger.log('interation is: ' + j);` statement in the nested `FOR` loop, so that you can determine on which iteration the error occurs.  Maybe one of the elements in your `attribs` array doesn't match the name in your ListItem.

Comment: You might want to add the Google Apps Script tag to your question instead of just Javascript.

Comment: Sandy Good - It seems to fail on the first iteration. SO says I don't have enough reputation to add any tag with google in it.